# how do I access my module in express?

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, npm

I install bootstrap with

```
npm install bootstrap --save
```

in my express project, then bootstrap is installed in `node_modules`, but how can I access the `js` and `css` in my jade file?

Comment: you should respond to answers or accept if any of them helped.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on how you configure your static server, e.g.:

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

So if `node_modules` is placed into `public` folder, your `jade` file will be:

```
script(src='/node_modules/bootstrap/js/file.js')
```

But better approach is use `bower_component` instead of `node_modules` on the client-side

Comment: Public folder is meant for resources like images, stylesheets, scripts or other files. **node_modules** are server packages.

Comment: Roger asked how he can access to js and css from `node_modules`

Comment: Yes, but this is definitely not the recommended approach how one should reference client modules from html.

Comment: Yes. Anyway, I answered how to access to js from client. And didn't recommend use `node_modules` instead of `bower` :)

Comment: Maybe :) I updated my answer. What is incorrect there now? I even recommend a good approach ))

Answer (score -1):

*Node_modules* is meant to use for server modules. *NPM* is server package management system.

You should use client package management system like [*bower*](http://bower.io/) for your client side modules i.e. Bootstrap.

Once you set up *bower*, you'll be able to reference **bower_components** in your *html* files.

Comment: Why you can't use `node_modules` for client-side? Sometimes `bower` doesn't contain necessary libs

Comment: can you please tell me what libraries are supposed to use in *html* from **node_modules**.

Comment: Can you explain me, why bower is more better. Anyway it depends on how you configure you static server, and where did you place your components (`node_modules` or `bower`)

Comment: It's not about which is better but appropriate. *static server* is meant for static resources like bootstrap, underscore. NPM modules are server programs, meant to use in backend i.e. Express.

Comment: Ok. How your answer can help to resolve Roger's problem?

Comment: Once bower is set up, one can reference any client packages from **bower_components** folder that holds all client side packages. And it is indeed recommended approach.